# Is it possible to stop Gson parsing?

Tags: java, android, parsing, gson

I just noticed Gson performances are not what I expected and some parsing processes are taking a lot of time. I'm not looking for another solution, my app is quite big and I don't want to alter its structure with something else like jackson.

My Android app allows the user to stop an http request with the back key. My code abort the request and basically stops the task. The thing is, it needs to wait for the method `gson.fromJson(result)` to abort the task. That instruction can last for a couple of seconds.

Is there any way to tell the gson object to abort the parsing process?

Comment: doesn't it have some sax-like parsing?

Comment: not really. it's taking a java.io.Reader and a class model in entry and returns an instance of the model from the data contained in the reader.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not familiar with GSON but you could close the underlying stream of JSON data (Inpustream) to end the parsing process with an exception, which you could catch. That should work in case the input data can be a Stream. I have just taken a look at the GSON API and the fromJson method takes a Reader parameter, which can be closed.
A bad way could be also to run it in a thread and call thread.stop().

Comment: I didn't think in the reader.close() idea. That's a nice idea thanks!

Comment: I just tested to close the reader while it's parsing and it works! It's throwing a JsonIOException as expected. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try to split the single gson call to several subcalls (since the parsed data seems to be huge when the request performs for seconds).

Basically I mean to parse every array element on it's own or parse attributes of class one by one instead doing the complete work in a single call. So you could interrupt that process more easily.

Comment: I see, well that's an interesting idea. How would you how to cut the java.io.Reader object though?

Comment: Didn't see that one comming ;-) I would try to read it to a string and parse it then, but first I would definitely try [that answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7513896/is-it-possible-to-stop-gson-parsing/7514061#7514061) since this might be the better idea

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK `Gson.fromJson()’Is a blocking method call which in Java can not be stopped.

Run parsing in the background thread. In this case youn can just leave it to run as it does not affect the UI part of your app.

Use AsynTask for this. Add a field `cancelled` to notify the task that it was cancelled so that it does not update UI at the end.

Comment: that's what I'm currently doing and I just wanted to improve performances. Thanks for your answer Peter.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do this by buffering response, and only doing parsing when everything is complete; or, stopping handling is cancelled.